# Forcing SSL on Wordpress crashes site?

Tags: https, nginx

So I have just installed a paid Comodo SSL on my website.

I can visit my website with https://homepage.com/ but the https appears grey. Currently that isn't my worry.

But when I visit the website without typing https, it doesn't redirect to https. So I installed iThemes Better Security, and when I force SSL site wide, I get the following error message:

```
The homepage.com page isn’t working

homepage.com redirected you too many times.
```

I have even tried to set it up in the server block by adding `return 301 https://homepage.com$request_uri;` as suggested from here: [CLICK](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-ssl-and-https-in-wordpress/)

I don't really know what else to do. I just want SSL to work site-wide, then I can move onto the greybar issue.

I am running Centos 7 + Nginx + OpenSSL

**EDIT:
This is my configuration through Nginx:**
I have disabled all wordpress plugins, and renamed .htaccess to something different and the error still persists. Only thing I can think of left is something in my server config. If it helps, I am using Cloudflare with SSL disabled for my domain.

```
server{
    listen       80;
   server_name  domain.com www.domain.com;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/domain_com/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/domain_com/domain.key;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    root   /var/www/data/domain.com/public_html/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 500M;

location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: it sounds like because you don't have a valid cert installed (the greyed out HTTPS stuff) the redirect rule is sending you back to the same page over an over again in a loop. that or a coding error. if its a rewrite rule, make sure the rule does not match `https` when its matching `http`.

Comment: When I run my site through: https://www.digicert.com/help/ This is the output: http://prntscr.com/au0tf5 Which I would assume means the certificate is valid. It appears green in the admin panel though.

Comment: When you mention rewrite rule, is their a specific rewrite of something I am looking for? Like the iThemes security plugin or something else?

Comment: Have you tried renaming .htaccess and seeing what happens?

Comment: I've done that, but it doesn't change anything. I have disabled all plugins as well. I am unsure as to what would be causing it from here as I manage the VPS and don't remember adding anything unusual for redirects. I added my server block config to the OP.

Comment: Paste your .htaccess in your post without any cache entries.  Also does your domain name match the domain in the URL in WP settings?

Comment: Steve, my server install was a duplicate copy of an existing server of mine.  I am going to be doing a clean install and setting everything up as I believe there are some modifications to either the site or nginx that I am unable to locate. This will give me a chance to ensure the installation goes through fully and error free. I will update back within 24 hours of my endeavor.